# How to use track by in ng-repeat having array in ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have two lists of locations from two different objects, like

1. Company Locations: `myCompany.locations`
2. TrpStop Locations: `load.customer.locations`

I want to select a location from myCompany using `<select>` option.

I am trying:

```
<div ng-repeat="load in load.loadStops">

   <select ng-model="load.customer.locations" ng-repeat="location as location.street1 for location in myCompany.locations track by location.id">
       <option value="" >&nbsp</option>
   </select>

</div>
```

> It seems that `track by` in location select isn't working, because the location is not preselected in select option.

Please guide me through how do I preselect the location?

Thanks.

Comment: produce a plunker

Comment: provide plunkr link

Comment: @SravyaNagumalli https://plnkr.co/edit/BoVF0oP7t5Q73NWBnihG?p=preview

Comment: @BadshahTracker please provide data as well.

Comment: @SravyaNagumalli https://plnkr.co/edit/BNYQrr?p=preview

Comment: @SravyaNagumalli please replace ng-mode with this one `ng-model="load.customer.locations"`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/mKVOJuJc96sIPbhte6PG?p=preview

Comment: @Sajeetharan please have a look over here https://plnkr.co/edit/7aH6ZNFzUX8iKYZmyy1y?p=preview

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat,

```
 <select ng-model="load.customer.locations" ng-options="location as location.street1 for location in myCompany.locations track by id">
 </select>
```

[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/mdt6i0DSLSPhpPeKaOUk?p=preview)

Comment: I am using ng-options but not working as intended. I want to preselect an option if it exists in load.customer.locations

Comment: just tell me how do I make the ng-model `load.customer.locations` as unique ng-model in each iteration. Could we do like `load.customer.locations.$index` or `load[$index].customer.locations` or kind of that? so that we can make the ng-model unique. It is going to solve the problem

Comment: it should be  [(ngModel)]="load[$index].customer.locations

Comment: You mean, we should replace `ng-model="load.customer.locations"` with this one